# Ternary operator with multiple condtions in Java throwing error

Tags: java, ternary-operator

This is my ternary condition in Java.

```
new_user_id.equals(userid) && new_key.equals(key) && !new_value.equals(value) ? updateValue() : System.out.println("New value already exists in DB");
```

I'm trying to match three conditions and call updateValue() function if all three conditions gets true. But still its throwing error "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable". Any ideas?

Comment: Throw everything from 'new' to right before '?' in parenthesis ()

Comment: ternary statements are meant to be used in assignments. This needs to be changed to an `if` statement

Answer (score 1):

[JLS-15.25. Conditional Operator `? :`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) says (in part)

> It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method.

Comment: Can you tell me what should be written?

Comment: You can't use `System.out.println` and you can't call a `void` method (with a ternary). You could use an `if-else`.

Comment: But I want to call a function if it returns true. I can write if-else, but I dont want to use it

Comment: You can call a function, but it must return a value (and it must be of the same type for both the second and third operand expressions).

Comment: So, the function should return a boolean value, right?

Comment: Any value, as long as both operations return the same type.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator is used for conditional variable assignment or something like:

```
System.out.println("You have " + items + (items == 1 ? "item." : "items."));
```

Therefore, it must return something. Use an `if` statement instead.